# I need to change my random number every time this particular button is pressed in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am needing to, every time the game is started over my random number to change. Keep in mind that the random number is accessed by a couple different classes. Here are a few code snippets from the python and .kv files.

Python File:

```
from kivy import *
import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class WannaPlay(Screen):
    pass


class Guesses(Screen):
    pass


class TimeToGuess(Screen):
    pass


class Winner(Screen):
    pass


class Loser(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManage(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file('guessinggame.kv')


class GuessingGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

    computer_num = random.randint(1, 10)
    random_num = str(computer_num)
    print(random_num)
    guesses_left = 3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GuessingGameApp().run()
```

.kv file:

```
ScreenManage:
    WannaPlay:
    Guesses:
    TimeToGuess:
    Winner:
    Loser:


<WannaPlay>:
    name: 'start'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: 'Want to Play the Guessing Game?'

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Button:
                name: 'yes'
                text: 'Yes'
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                    root.manager.current = 'guess_choice'

            Button:
                name: 'no'
                text: 'No'
                on_release:
                    app.stop()


<Guesses>
    name: 'guess_choice'
    id: guesses_choice
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        Label:
            text: 'You Will Have 3 guesses. Are You Ready?'
        Button:
            name: 'yes_guess'
            text: 'YES'
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = 'time_to_guess'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                app.guesses_left = int(3)





<TimeToGuess>

    name: 'time_to_guess'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        Label:
            text: 'Guess a number between 1 and 10'
        Label:
            id: guesses_left
            text: 'Guesses Left: '

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            TextInput:
                id: guess
                name: 'user_guess'

            Button:
                text: 'Submit Answer'
                on_release:

                    app.guesses_left = int(app.guesses_left) - int(1)
                    guesses_left.text = 'Guesses Left: ' + str(app.guesses_left)
                    root.manager.current = 'winner' if guess.text == app.random_num else 'loser' if guess.text != app.random_num and app.guesses_left == int(0) else 'time_to_guess'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                    guess.text = ''





<Winner>
    name: 'winner'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: 'You have Won!'
        Label:
            text: 'Would You Like To Play Again?'
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Button:
                text: 'Yes'
                on_release:
                    app.guesses_left = int(3)
                    root.manager.current = 'guess_choice'
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0


            Button:
                text: 'No'
                on_release:
                    app.stop()
<Loser>
    name: 'loser'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text:'You have Lost!'
        Label:
            text: 'Would You Like To Play Again?'
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Button:
                text: 'Yes'
                on_press:
                    root.manager.current = 'guess_choice'
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
            Button:
                text: 'No'
                on_release:
                    app.stop()
```

So, when yes is clicked. I need a new random number to generate that can still be accessed from different classes easily. Thsnk you in advance for the help

Comment: Post a minimal runnable example. You don't even have any code attempting to use the random number you generated, so there's nothing to point out how to fix.

Comment: I have updated the code blocks to include more code to show how the random number is used. I just need a new random number each time the user wants to play again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the start of your `kv` file add the line:

```
#:import random random
```

Then, wherever you need to reinitialize the `random_num`, just add the line:

```
app.random_num = str(random.randint(1, 10))
```

For example, in your `<Loser>` rule:

```
<Loser>
    name: 'loser'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text:'You have Lost!'
        Label:
            text: 'Would You Like To Play Again?'
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Button:
                text: 'Yes'
                on_press:
                    root.manager.current = 'guess_choice'
                    app.random_num = str(random.randint(1, 10))
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
            Button:
                text: 'No'
                on_release:
                    app.stop()
```

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you! This exactly what I needed. Note I also has to reassign the random_num variable to the computer_num variable again to make the change for the login in my .kv file. Thanks again!!!!!

Comment: I didn't update the `computer_num` variable because it is not used anywhere else in your posted code.

Comment: I see what you mean. Looks like I added some extra logic that was not needed.